# Why does the memory consumption grows when using more threads on Linux? (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory, openmp

**Program:**

I created a C++ calculation program for high volume of data, which could be run on 1 or more threads. (via config file)

The program environment is the following: C++, OpenMp, Redhat-x64, malloc/free

**Results on Linux:**

- When I run it on 1 thread, process size is 177 MB.
- When I run it on 2 threads, process size is 317 MB.
- When I run it on 4 threads, process size is 600 MB.

**Results on Windows:**

- Process size still the same regardless the number of threads used, 110MB.

**Question:**

Why does the memory consumption grows when using more threads on Linux?

Comment: Which memory, virtual, resident, shared?

Comment: Each thread has its own stack?

Comment: I just use standard c++ malloc allocator, I do not know how linux works after that.

Comment: Is this real, or are you somehow seeing the same memory reported for each thread as they all share a memory space, so multiplying the real memory requirement by the number of threads? What are you using to determine the size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fair guess is that `delete` in Linux will cache released memory for future `new` requests, just as it does on Windows, but Linux has a cache per thread whereas Windows has a cache per process.

(More accurately, it would be the C++ runtime library that determines how such a cache works).

Comment: I do not find any information about this cache, is there a name for it?

Comment: It's considered an implementation detail, without an explicit name. It's also somewhat of an abstraction. I believe that some implementations will have multiple pools or caches, to keep freed blocks of the same size grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/proc/<PID>/maps`, or better [`pmap(1)`](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/pmap.1.html), to figure out where the pages go.

Answer (score 1):

Every thread you start needs a stack allocated to run it, and memory for any thread-local variables. I'm not entirely sure that 150Mb per thread looks sensible, but a thread local array could cause something like that.